# Are questions about how stunts are performed considered on-topic?

Tags: discussion

I'm wanting to ask a question related to the performance of stunts within martial arts movies, particularly a specific movement in the movie Birth of the Dragon.

In the movie, Master Wong performs a movement in which he spins over an opponent's arm (timestamp included):

My biggest question surrounds the concept of ensuring safety with such a movement, which I can flesh out in greater detail in a main post, if it's on-topic. However, I'm not sure if asking how stunts are performed and the safety procedures surrounding them is on-topic for main.

---

Are questions about how stunts are performed considered on-topic?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Questions about stunts are indeed on topic here.  We even have a [tag for them](https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/stunts).